# Open popup on click of points in jchartfx

Tags: jchartfx

I want to open the popup on click of points in jchartfx to display the detail information about that point. How can i pass the unique id to display the detail information dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about performing it *on click*, but the jChartFX samples include [a downloadable example](http://support.softwarefx.com/jChartFX/article/2501235#!2601046) (with [some code](http://support.softwarefx.com/jChartFX/article/2501235#!2501064)) of doing this via *tooltips* (i.e. on hover).

Basically, you need to handle the 'gettip' event:

```
chart1.on("gettip", onGetTip);
```

The handler should create a div with the content for your tooltip:

```
function onGetTip(args) {
    divInTooltip = document.getElementById('tipChartInfo');
    args.tooltipDiv.appendChild(divInTooltip);
    args.replaceDiv = true;
    var dataPoint = args.getPoint();

    // Custom code based on the data point...
    ...
}
```

Regarding your specific question, the data point that the tooltip relates to is available via `args.getPoint()` .